# Javax Validation not catching Inner fields for the POJO

Tags: java, validation

I have a added javax.validations to my Pojo as below.

```
 class A {

    @NotEmpty
    private List<Detail> detail;

}

Class Detail {
    @NotNull
    private Name name;
}
```

And I am using the below code to do the validation.

1. `Set<ConstraintViolation<A>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(a);` - Finds only if the detail is null or empty. But doesn't find if Name is null,

Is this how the validation works, I want to validate the complete POJO with its refereed fields  but here only one level of validation is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the @Valid annotation to `detail` to cause validation checking to cascade into it.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Valid.html